# Netcat says 'operation not permitted'

Tags: cygwin, netcat

I thought I could easily copy a tgz from a linux box to a windows box (cygwin) by doing this on the linux box:

```
nc -vv -l 4444 < file.tgz
```

And this on the windows box:

```
nc -vv 10.13.13.2 4444 > file.tgz
```

But whenever I do that the windows box complains:

```
10.13.13.2: inverse host lookup failed:  : Operation not permitted
(UNKNOWN) [10.13.13.2] 4444 (?) : Connection timed out
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually that the socket has been closed already. Try this on the linux one (first):

```
nc -l -p 4444 -w5 < file.tgz
```

Then this on the windows box (wihin 5 seconds of the first):

```
nc -w5 10.13.13.2 4444 > file.tgz
```

The `-w` argument sets a timeout on the connection (5 seconds, in this case). Also, `-l` sets up listen mode, but you need to specify the listen port with `-p`.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, what exactly are you trying to do? Transfer a file from a Linux box to a Windows box?

I always use WinSCP. It connects to the Linux box's sshd and transfers files over SFTP.

Comment: Not all boxes run an sshd, as was the case when I asked this question.